# Groupby 1 or 2 variables, depending on if condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, group

I would like to group `data` by groups either `group1` or `group1` and `group2` conditional on a `by_group` bool.

```
grouped_DF <- function(data, by_group = TRUE, group1='year',group2='country') {
  data <- data %>%
    group_by(
      if (by_group) c(group1, group2) else group1
    ) %>%
    mutate(...)
    ungroup()
  
  return(data)
}
```

However, I can't can't manage to find a solution.

I get a first error related to sizes that do not agree: `if (by_group) c(group1, group2) else` group1 `must be size 1115451 or 1, not 1115452.`.

If I set `by_group` to FALSE, I get: `Caused by error in pick():! Selections can't have missing values.`

Without the condition and if I group simply by `group1` the function works as expected.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

**Data Example.**

```
data(mtcars)

grouped_DF <- function(data, by_group = TRUE, group1='carb',group2='gear') {
  data <- data %>%
    group_by(
      if (by_group) c(group1, group2) else group1
    ) %>%
    summarise(
      disp = mean(disp),
      hp = mean(hp)
    )   
  ungroup()
  return(data)
}

mtcars_grouped=grouped_DF(mtcars,by=TRUE)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code where you actually call the function so we can see what you are passing in.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. Just added the data example using `mtcars`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `pick` in `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)

grouped_DF <- function(data, by_group = TRUE, group1='carb',group2='gear') {
  group_col <- if (by_group) c(group1, group2) else group1

  data <- data %>%
    group_by(pick(all_of(group_col))) %>%
    summarise(
      disp = mean(disp),
      hp = mean(hp)
    )  %>% 
  ungroup()
  
  return(data)
}

grouped_DF(mtcars, by_group = TRUE)

# A tibble: 11 × 4
#    carb  gear  disp    hp
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3 201.  104  
# 2     1     4  84.2  72.5
# 3     2     3 346.  162. 
# 4     2     4 121.   79.5
# 5     2     5 108.  102  
# 6     3     3 276.  180  
# 7     4     3 416.  228  
# 8     4     4 164.  116. 
# 9     4     5 351   264  
#10     6     5 145   175  
#11     8     5 301   335
```